# Why does ksh allow unpaired quotes while bash does not?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ksh

When I execute following command, on bash shell I get error but on Korn shell it runs perfectly fine. The only difference is missing single quote at the end of awk, after }. Could you help me understand why?

```
echo `echo "a b c d" | awk '{ print $1 }`
```

Comment: ksh is just wrong on this, quotes have to be paired xor escaped.

Comment: It doesn't give an error in my ksh, either, (os x). Surprising!

Comment: An error is correct behavior, so it would appear that it is running perfectly fine in bash but incorrectly in Korn rather than the other way around.

Comment: I really hope someone comes up with a real answer for this, because that is very surprising.

Comment: Which version of korn shell is this with? The preferred way of executing commands is $() which has the major advantage of nesting. The only advantage of `` is that it is one less character to type.

Comment: ksh is just adding an extra single quote for some reason, I don't think this is intended though. The provided command shows this:
+ awk '{ print $1 }'
+ echo 'a b c d'
+ echo a
a

Comment: It appears that some "syntax forgiveness" was built into the ksh parser, intentionally or otherwise. You see a lot of this in HTML. Yuk.

Comment: @user28458 : What do you get for `echo ${.sh.version}` ? If that fails, try `ksh --version`. What is the output of `uname -srv` ?  (could this really be `pdksh`?) Good luck..

Answer (score 1):

In the Korn shell, both back ticks and quotes can be left unmatched, the tokenizer will try and guess where either will end and match them accordingly.

Examples:

```
/home/ufierro # echo "`echo ah" 
+ echo ah
+ echo ah
ah

/home/ufierro # echo `echo 'hello world` 
+ echo 'hello world'
+ echo hello world
hello world
```

Notice how both examples show a different case for the behavior mentioned above.
The first example shows how, a single back tick within double quotes was completed during parsing and the second example shows how a single quote inside back ticks was completed as well.

Comment: Thanks. I guessed that it might be trying to guess but I wanted to know why :) Wouldn't it be error prone or there is some concrete logic so that it wouldn't be?

Comment: It's a real specific behavior that only occurs within a specific set of quotes/back-ticks, it'll match the token being parsed and try to finish quoting to prevent errors, ugly indeed but hardly error prone unless you intend on producing an error this way.